# Editor (DevDemon) h1 Button

Tags: redactor, editor

I want to have  `p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5` Buttons in the Editor by DevDemon.

How do I do this? Do I really need to hack some php or js files?

I enabled "Formating Tags" in Advanced Settings. But these Tag Buttons still don't show up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they have some [half-finished docs on adding buttons programatically](http://www.devdemon.com/docs/editor/create_button.html) ... you should really [contact their support](http://www.devdemon.com/support/) to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, shame on me. The solution is so simple:

DevDemon Support pointed out, that all the Text Formating options are in the «pilcrow sign» Button:

[image]